# Splitting a point vector based on a date attribute within the QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler, splitting, date

I have now a model which processes two layers of points corresponding to observations at 'Time_1' and 'Time_2'. It counts the observation per quadrats in a grid and obtains two outputs: a grid with the accumulation per quadrat (T1+T2) and another grid with the variation per quadrat (T2-T1).

But, as a previous step: is it possible to generate the two input layers 'Time_1' and 'Time_2' from the original point layer? So far I've done the splitting of the layers outside of the Modeler. The ideal would be to automate this part as well.

I would need to split the table based on the event_date (yyyymmdd) attribute. For this, i would need to find the middle date of the series (median), then split the table in half: before and after that date. How to do all this from the Modeler? I imagine it's from the calculator, but I can't....

Thanks for your support

[image: The model so far]